# Can an application be rejected if on 1st launch user is asked to Activate app via Safari?

Tags: iphone, ipad

possibly a simple question, but I couldn't find definitive answer (see below for excerpt from HIG) myself that would state below scenario as 'unacceptable' and will result in app being rejected:

1. On 1st application launch after installation user will see an alert
   asking to activate the app.
2. Tapping "Activate" will open Safari and display a web page with
   "Activate" button.
3. Tapping it will launch my app via URL-scheme, pass some server
   generated data and allow user to enter main UI.
4. The application will be locked until user activates.

If you need more context on why and how, please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701574/how-to-track-downloads-on-ios5-without-udid/7704341#7704341).

**Mobile HIG (as of 2011-10-12):**
"If possible, avoid requiring users to indicate their agreement to your EULA when they first start your application. Without an agreement displayed, users can enjoy your application without delay. However, even though this is the preferred user experience, it might not be feasible in all cases. If you must display a license agreement within your application, do so in a way that harmonizes with your user interface and causes the least inconvenience to users."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there's similar cases where an app is almost useless until the user registers to some service, take Instagram as an example.

I'd suggest however that you solve this by not forcing the user to leave your app. Instead, present the user with a web view within your app where you politely describe why it is necessary for the user to go through the activation process.

We've done something similar before (EULA presented modally within a web view on first launch, which could only be dismissed by accepting it) and it was approved right away.

Comment: Get it, but the whole reason behind leaving app is that the page in Safari will access Safari's cookie storage, read a value (or generate if cookie not present) and pass it to my app... AFAIK, Safari's cookie cannot be accessed via `UIWebView`.

Comment: Ok I see... hard to give any advice without knowing what you're trying to achieve. Couldn't you do it without cookies, by employing a php script / mySQL database on a server or something like that? Even if you do it your way - what if the user deletes cookies after activating your app?

Comment: more context is provided in my question (referenced a link to it).

Comment: Mhh... tricky. I don't have a proper alternative, but my gut feeling says that your approach - while maybe without alternative - is clumsy in terms of user experience and prone to error. Furthermore I can imagine Apple not approving it, because the whole clumsiness is required for your statistics only, not for enhancing the user experience or legal reasons. What if you provide some promo code within your ad and lure the user into entering it into your app by allowing it to unlock some minor bonus functionality? No guarantee for the user to enter it, but no guarantee for cookies enabled either

Comment: That confirms my worries that I'd have to drop my idea :( If no one post possibly better answer till tomorrow, I'll accept yours. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks delirus, you're welcome. Sorry I couldn't help you out with some sort of solution. I'll let you know if I can think of something helpful. Good luck!